# Is there a way to do SSRS Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-expression

I am working on a SQl Server Report Services project and the report I am creating requires some custom code.  It seems that [all expressions must be in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345237.aspx) and I figured if there was an 'easy' way to switch that over to be C#, it would be helpful.

EDIT:

Well, I decided to move my code to another C# assembly that follows the patterns like [this example.](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SS2008!File%20Share%20Data%20Processing%20Extension%20Sample)

Comment: those 'vb' expressions look just like the Access ones! I wonder where the Access dev team went ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) rather than VB.NET, so it's not .NET, it's an embedded scripting language. Therefore I would expect that there's no way to switch to C#.

Comment: well I was close in believing it was VBScript.

Comment: For the record, I really hated that it is VB* when I had to create a few records in our last large app. I'm not 100% sure it is VBA, but it looks so suspiciously like VBA, and it's the internal automation language for many Microsoft products anyway. Hopefully in the future they'll switch to .NET in general :D

Comment: Oh, and, VB is VB, no matter if VB6, VBA, VBS or VB.NET. I don't like any of these. That's likely the motivation of asking to switch to C# as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reports are using something more along the lines of VBScript (**Edit**: OregonGhost says VBA which actually makes more sense than VBScript) than VB.NET (and very limited at that). I have not seen any way of switching it over to C#, and I would like to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. And the language as described my MSDN is not really VB.NET, but Visual Basic